# Vehicle Km Costs are included while on ferry in Here API

Tags: here-api

When I ask for toll costs I don't get ferry costs (to be implemented I hope). But in the route cost I see vehicle costs. If I understand correctly only the costs per km are taking into account for a vehicle (so I have to add hour costs to km). To my suprise the costs also takes km while on ferry into account.
I entered 50 cents per km, and I see about 30 euro of vehicle costs between Dover and Calais.

Here is [a link](https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy&cost_optimize=1&driver_cost=25&vehicle_cost=0.5&currency=EUR&rollup=none&detail=1&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=6&height=4.0m&trailerHeight=4.0m&vehicleWeight=40.0t&limitedWeight=40.0t&disabledEquipped=0&passengersCount=1&tiresCount=10&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=3.5m&waypoint0=geo!50.9469214,1.8560884&waypoint1=geo!51.1219769,1.3114455&metricsystem=metric&maneuverattributes=none&routeattributes=gr&mode=fastest;truck&jsonattributes=41&combinechange=true&linkattributes=none&legattributes=none&language=en-us)

> {"faultCode":"s9205992a-ff30-4188-8a82-e721643f247c","responseCode":"401","message":"This is not a valid app_id and app_code pair. Please verify that the values are not swapped between the app_id and app_code and the values provisioned by HERE (either by your customer representative or via http://developer.here.com/myapps) were copied correctly into the request."}

Answer (score 0):

Vehicle costs are calculated irrespective of the vehicle being driven or not in the current routing api. However there are plans of implementing the above ask soon. Watch out for updates in the development page. 
Total distance as per your query: 56.743 km
Vehicle km cost defined: 0.5 cents
Total Vehicle cost calculated:  56.743 * 0.5 = 28.37 Euro

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice to have vehicle costs per hour and vehicle costs per km. Hour costs should always be used in the calculation, km costs only when actual driving occurs.

Comment: Regarding updates, how can we know/notified an update is implemented and what the changes are? Eg this month the toll cost extension api went from v2.5.7 to 2.5.8, but I couldn't find what the changes are.

Comment: You can view the change log and pdf documentation for current and previous versions of HERE APIs in developer.here.com/documentation/versions.

Comment: Super! Nice overview